# Requests made by Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How do I see the requests made by the extensions running in Chrome in the background on a particular website?

Comment: Extensions can initiate requests from content scripts and the background page. For content scripts, just open the devtools for a specific page. To get the devtools for the background page, [see this picture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10258029/938089?where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension).

Answer (score 1):

You can do that for extensions you are developing by looking at your extension / app background page (right click on the extension -> manage extensions -> inspect views under your extension).

Then open the debug panel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) when looking at the background page of your extension (only debug extensions), you'll be able to see the network traffic for it.

Comment: I am not developing any extension. Have to do it for some other extension from the web-store.

Comment: Fiddler worked.
Sadly, wireshark doesn't detect my interface. :(

Comment: doesn't make sense, what happened with wireshark?

Comment: It doesn't detect my network interface.
Seems the problem is something related to Wireshark supporting only PPP connections.

Comment: not sure, fiddler is a good tool too..can you give points to both answers?

Comment: @user1471283 The method described in this answer will work even if it isn't your extension. Just make sure you check the developer mode box.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor all HTTP traffic on you PC with [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).

Comment: @user1471283 Ok, wasn't sure about that. Fiddler should do the trick then.

Comment: Will try it out and revert.